# How to put filtering feature in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic mobile application there's a filter search button but I am having a hard time how to filter array of objects.

Assuming I have an array of objects structured like this

```
  initializeItems() {
this.items = [
{Place:"Dumaguete city", date:"February 2 2018"},
{Place:"Sibulan", date:"February 2 2018"},
{Place:"Bacong", date:"February 3 2018"},
{Place:"Manila", date:"February 4 2018"},
{Place:"Netherlands", date:"February 4 2018"},
{Place:"India", date:"February 5 2018"},
{Place:"USA", date:"February 7 2018"}
];
```

Filter codes below:

```
  getItems(ev: any) {
console.log(this.items);
// Reset items back to all of the items
this.initializeItems();

// set val to the value of the searchbar
let val = ev.target.value;

// if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

}

How do I put filter feature in a array of objects?

Comment: so what did not work with the above code?

Comment: what do you mean by `how do i put filter feature in a array of objects?`. You want to do something like `this.items = this.items.filterByVal(val)`?

Comment: here is an implementation of [filter pipe](https://github.com/ziaulain/Angular4-pipe-json-search) in angular 4.

Comment: hello. if the items is just an array this code works perfectly fine. but assuming i have a array of objects as to what i stated above, the getItems gives me an error stating item.tolowerCase is not a function

Comment: so im wondering as to how i filter in an array of objects

Comment: giving me a full object search

Answer (score 0):

You need to search in your objects values, not the array item

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.Place.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
    item.date.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()));
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir vessel. i added >-1 for it to work perfectly

Comment: hi sir. what if my date is a timestamp? it gives me date.tolowercase is not a function

Comment: convert both item.date and val to number and compare;
(+new Date(item.date)) === +new Date(val);

Answer (score 0):

The items has several objects and every object has to two members (Place and date). In the filter you must specify what member should be filtered. In the below code I have choosen `Place`.

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.Palce.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

You could choose another one or both.

**Update**

If you want your filter works for both member, just add new condition with `or` operator.

```
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
          return (item.Place.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.date.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
```

As you have mentioned in the comment, you want to have the `date` member of your objects as `timestamp` and you want to have an ability to filter it too.

Well, Javascript `Date` object has several constructors, one of them takes `timestamp`. So, we can use it to solve the problem.

```
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
          this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
              return (item.Place.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 || (new Date(Number(item.date))).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
          })
        }
```

or

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        const placeResult = item.Place.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        const theDate = new Date(Number(item.date));
        const dateResult = theDate.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        return placeResult || dateResult;
    })
}
```

Comment: i wanted both. how to structure that?

Comment: hi sir abbas. what if my date is a timestamp? it gives me .tolowercase  is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the property/properties you want check against, currently you are just testing the object in the array which will check against the object itself not the properties within.

```js
var items = [
{Place:"Dumaguete city", date:"February 2 2018"},
{Place:"Sibulan", date:"February 2 2018"},
{Place:"Bacong", date:"February 3 2018"},
{Place:"Manila", date:"February 4 2018"},
{Place:"Netherlands", date:"February 4 2018"},
{Place:"India", date:"February 5 2018"},
{Place:"USA", date:"February 7 2018"}
];

var val = 'Manila';

if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  items = items.filter((item) => {
   if( item.Place.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ){
       var node = document.createElement("LI");              
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(item.Place);        
      node.appendChild(textnode); 
      document.getElementById('filter').appendChild(node);
    }
  })
}
```